# Python Script Takes more than 6 hours to execute

Tags: python, pandas, git

I am new to scripting, have a python script which is importing the pulls requests from all the repositories in an organization. Script works but 2 issues are there.
1. It taken more than 6 hours to complete or throw an error message.
2. Each auth token has a limit of the API calls, i get an error "rate limit exceeded" for the auth tokens, in order to avoid this i am using more than 4 auth tokens and creating a loop.

Below is the script. what can i do to make this run quicker?

Comment: Your are just setting `program_not_ended = False` in the try-block. So whenever an exception raises the loop starts again.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer reason to set this up is to make sure that the script runs for all the repositories and related pull requests, if i take this out program might end abruptly and give me a partial set of results.

Comment: @Javed based on what you've seen so far, where do you think most of the execution time is spent? I.e. is each call of `pr_df = pull_pr_comments(repo, reponame, pr_df)` really slow, as it goes through a single repo?

Comment: @JethroCao That is correct. For repos that have less pr's it completes with out any error, but for some repos it will never complete. Because these repos have more than 1500 pr's and with one auth token it exceeds Rate Limit, but when we use another auth token it starts from start of the repo and it exceeds the limit again.

Comment: @Javed Hmm this actually sounds like an interesting problem, I'll have a go at tackling it and will keep you posted.

Comment: One more thing, so when you say it takes >6 hours to execute, what's the end result? You get a partial incomplete list of all the PRs you're looking for? It errors out? Or you just didn't let it run for longer than that?

Comment: @jethro i have let it run for more than 24 hours but i get a rate limit exceeded error. There are 5 repos that i need to exclude, if i exclude those then it takes more than 10 hours and gives me the complete results.Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you give me some test repos to work with? A mix of small and larger sized ones preferably; a few would do. Ofc this is under the assumption that this info isn't security sensitive (if so, then I'll just test it out on repos like Python, Linux repo, etc.)

Comment: @jethro Apologies, cannot provide the details as these repos are private and have sensitive data. Any way you can test this with public repos ? .Thank you.